# VBA Target.Address to Two Cells

Tags: vba, excel

I have to build a nested filter structure in Excel using VBA. The approach is to build two data validation lists that contain sorting indexes. I have three possible soring indexes, which is lastName, FirstName and Company. Since in the sort function doesn't allow indexes to be referred outside of the sorting range. I build those 6 possible combinations of the indexes, such as below.

```
Sub Macro_Sort1()
Sheets("Reports").Range("F1:CT10000").Sort Key1:=Sheets("Reports").Range("I1"), Order1:=xlAscending, Key2:=Sheets("Reports").Range("J1"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
End Sub
```

And now I need to assign this macro to those two data validation list, like

```
If Target.Address = "$B$1" and "$B$2" Then
    Select Case Target.Value2
         Case "Last" and "First"
            Call Macro_Sort1
         Case "Last" and "Company"
            Call Macro_Sort2
         Case "First" and "Last"
            Call Macro_Sort3
         Case "First" and "Company"
            Call Macro_Sort4
         Case "Company" and "Last"
            Call Macro_Sort5
         Case "Company" and "First"
            Call Macro_Sort6
   End Select
End if
End Sub
```

However, obviously it tells me there is an error with the Target.Address Sentence in regards to THEN.

Please help me figure out if there is other approach to achieve this.

Thanks in advance!

**Update:**

As I mentioned, I have two filters, and the first one can be used independently, it has macro assigned to it like below:

```
Sub Macro_Sort1()
Sheets("Reports").Range("F1:CT10000").Sort Key1:=Sheets("Reports").Range("I1"), Header:=xlYes, Order1:=xlAscending
End Sub
```

So before the code for both filters there would be code like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Address = "$B$17" Then
    Select Case Target.Value2
         Case "Last"
            Call Macro_Sort1
         Case "First"
            Call Macro_Sort2
         Case "Company"
            Call Macro_Sort3
    End Select
```

Based on some advice, I appended this part after the previous one.

```
ElseIf Target.Address(0, 0) = "$B$17" Or Target.Address(0, 0) = "$B$18" Then
       SortUsingDataValidation Range("B17").Value, Range("B18").Value
End If
End Sub

Private Sub SortUsingDataValidation(sFirst As String, sSecond As String)
Dim oDict As Object

Set oDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
With ThisWorknook.shhets("Reports")
Set oDict("Last") = .Range("I1")
Set oDict("First") = .Range("J1")
Set oDict("Company") = .Range("K1")
If oDict.exists(sFirst) And oDict.exists(sSecond) Then
   .Range("F1:CT10000").Sort Key1:=oDict(sFirst), Order1:=xlAscending, key2:=oDict(sSecond), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
End If
End With
End Sub
```

Although it is really nice approach, it fails to run. There is no error or any message boxes pop up. So please check if it is code of first filter affecting the double filter code.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Consider renaming `Macro_SortX` procedures to meaningful names that start with a verb (e.g. `SortByFooBarBaz`), and dropping the obsolete and utterly useless `Call` statements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edited:

- added `Application.Transpose()` method to `Target` range since `B1:B2` is a one-column "vertical" range while `Join()` expects an array which corresponds to a one-row "horizontal" range
- added some code "flavours" to deal with different environments

Changing approach

```
If Target.Address = "$B$1:$B$2" Then
    Dim strng As String
    Dim pos as Long

    strng = "1LastFirst,2LastCompany,3FirstLast,4FirstCompany,5CompanyLast,6CompanyLast"
    pos = Instr(strng,Join (Application.Transpose(Target),""))
    If pos > 0 then Application.Run "Macro_Sort" & Mid(strng,pos-1,1)
End If
```

Finally some environment advices:

In case you're running this code inside a Worksheet event handler then

- `If Target.Address = "$B$1:$B$2"` could be `True` only in a `Worksheet_SelectionChange` handler, while other relevant handlers dealing with a `Target` range parameter would detect only a one-cell Range

  For instance should you need to run it inside a `Worksheet_Change` event handler then you'd need to change the check into some:

  `If Not Intersect(Target, Range ("B1:B2")) Is Nothing Then`

  Which could also do in many other different cases
- Subs to be called by `Application.Run` method must be placed in any module but not in a Worksheet one

Comment: Your `instr` is backwards? Otherwise I like it!

Comment: If you mean "InstrRev" then no, it isn't. If you mean I go back 1 position in "strng" then consider I could actually have placed the number at the end of every substring ("LasFirst1, LastCompany2,...") and go onwards in "strng" using" Mid(strng,pos+Len(Join(target,"")),1)". But I found it too verbose.

Comment: Stealing my correct answer, this means war, Just Kidding, this deserves it, good job.

Comment: @ScottCraner sorry I actually wanted to put in a shorter alternative to Select Case block

Comment: Don't apologize for a better solution.  It deserves the correct answer and anyone who would truly get upset losing to a better answer is petty and does not understand why this forum exists.  It is good for everyone when a better method is found.

Comment: @ScottCraner well, thank you. And your words should be carved just below the SO logo!

Answer (score 4):

A couple of things;

The address will be "B1:B2"

And to do multiple test with Select Case we want to search for True and format it something like a IF/ElseIF:

```
If target.Address(0, 0) = "B1:B2" Then
    Select Case True
         Case Range("B1") = "Last" And Range("B2") = "First"
            Call Macro_Sort1
         Case Range("B1") = "Last" And Range("B2") = "Company"
            Call Macro_Sort2
         Case Range("B1") = "First" And Range("B2") = "Last"
            Call Macro_Sort3
         Case Range("B1") = "First" And Range("B2") = "Company"
            Call Macro_Sort4
         Case Range("B1") = "Company" And Range("B2") = "Last"
            Call Macro_Sort5
         Case Range("B1") = "Company" And Range("B2") = "First"
            Call Macro_Sort6
   End Select
End If
```

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> If Target.Address = "$B$1" And "$B$2" Then
> ```

This is a syntax error, because `If {boolean-expression} Then` requires, well, a *Boolean expression* - and you've confused VBA with the `And {string-literal}` part of that expression.

You could construct a *Boolean expression* with the `And` keyword, like this:

```
{boolean-expression} And {boolean-expression}
```

In other words, you could have done:

```
If Target.Address = "$B$1" And Target.Address = "$B$2" Then
```

But as you would suspect, that logic is bound to always return `False`, because if `Target.Address` is equal to `"$B$1"` then it can't *also* be equal to `"$B$2"`.

[Scott's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37554321/1188513) has the rest of the solution.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to add in another approach because it's generally not a good idea to have 6 different macros to do essentially the same thing. It will work, but it's more code to maintain, making future changes more difficult.

In the code below, the values of the validation boxes are passed into a function that (1) links each value to a corresponding range, (2) sorts based on the corresponding ranges.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address(0, 0) = "B1" Or Target.Address(0, 0) = "B2" Then
        SortUsingDataValidation Range("B1").Value, Range("B2").Value
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub SortUsingDataValidation(sFirst As String, sSecond As String)
        Dim oDict As Object

        'Create a dictionary (or any collection) to hold references from a data validation
        'String to its corresponding cell reference
        Set oDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Reports")
            Set oDict("First") = .Range("I1")
            Set oDict("Last") = .Range("J1")
            Set oDict("Company") = .Range("K1")
            If oDict.exists(sFirst) And oDict.exists(sSecond) Then
                .Range("F1:CT10000").Sort Key1:=oDict(sFirst), Order1:=xlAscending, Key2:=oDict(sSecond), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
            End If
        End With
    End Sub
```

Comment: May I ask why would you dim A1 as the range and never use it again?

Comment: @JosephLin My apologies there. That was a line of code I used to perform a test unrelated to your procedure. I will edit my code above to remove the lines so it's not confusing for future users.

Comment: That's very nice of you, thanks! And actually because I have other data validation lists in this specific worksheet, so the first part of the your code is built after `Elseif`, and I append the second part right after the sub change. However it was not working, there is no error or any message box pop up? Do you think there could be any thing wrong?

Comment: And as FYI, I do have another 3 macros that are assigned to the three items in B1 data validations list. Could this be the cause?

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing the entirety of the code and/or testing it. You can do some debugging to see if your base code actually calls the function. One quick and easy debugging method is to include a `MsgBox` inside of the `Private Sub SortUsing...` method call. (Something like `MsgBox "CheckPoint"` in a new line after `Dim oDict...`).  If the message box displays, then we know that the method is being called and we can further debug. Also, it may help if you edit your Original Post and include any of the code you think may help us debug.

Comment: Looked at the update, and the problem may be with the `ElseIf` block. It seems that the `If` part will fire and the `ElseIf` does not get called. (After all, they both seem to be testing for the same thing, so the `ElseIf` runs only if the `If` fails, which it shouldn't). Did you try debugging with a MsgBox?

Comment: I have tried debugging it, but nothing came up. And I have also tried deleting the if part only using your code, hoping it will achieve the same results as my code when leaving the second sort blank. it also didn't work.

Comment: is there any way that could incorporate these two together. I noticed since you have assign the second key in the dictionary UsingSortDataValidation,  leaving the second blank won't trigger the sort.